# Unable to run Microsoft Edge with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, wdio

I try run edge with WebDriverIO but the browser doesn't open up and end up with error like this in the command line
[image]

Here my setup for the capabilities. I try to run with chrome and firefox, it run smoothly.

```
 capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: "MicrosoftEdge",
      maxInstances: 5,
    },
]
```

Please help me, if you have a solution to this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install edge driver if haven't, use the following command

```
yarn add @sitespeed.io/edgedriver
```

then update the wdio config to include this.

```
services: ['edgedriver']
```

I finally ended up running tests using [this](https://juliapottinger.com/run-webdriverio-tests-on-microsoft-edge/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20your%20tests%20to,select%20the%20correct%20operating%20system.&text=Open%20Microsoft%20browser%20and%20get%20the%20version%20that%20you%20have%20downloaded)